Force Mockito to return null instead of emtpy list
I have a simple test with mocked Properties class:
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoReturnListTest {
    @Mock
    Properties myProperties;
    
    @Test
    public void propertiesTest() {
        Set<String> propertyNames = myProperties.stringPropertyNames();
        System.out.println(propertyNames);
    }
}

I have not created any stubbing for stringPropertyNames method, yet Mockito is returning an empty set when I call it. The output of the test is:
[]

How can I instruct Mockito to return null for all methods instead of empty collection? (In reality I have much bigger class with many List<> getSomething() methods, which I wish to return null)
I know I could stub the method like that:
    @Test
    public void propertiesTest2() {
        Set<String> propertyNames = myProperties.stringPropertyNames();
        when(myProperties.stringPropertyNames()).thenReturn(null);
        System.out.println(propertyNames);
    }

But I would like to make some sort of automatic stubbing for all methods to return null be default.

Write your own Answer class that overrides the answer method to always return null. It's a functional interface, so you can write it succinctly using a lambda.
Then, to use this Answer class for your mocked class, use the mock method instead of the @Mock annotation:
Answer<Object> myAnswer = (invocation) -> null;
Properties myProperties = mock(Properties.class, myAnswer);

If you want this answer to be the default for all mocks, change your default Mockito configuration by creating a class in your CLASSPATH called org.mockito.configuration.MockitoConfiguration (see doc for details). Make sure you define it in the org.mockito.configuration package and that its name is MockitoConfiguration.
In your MockitoConfiguration class, override the getDefaultAnswer() method to return your own Answer object.

what is MyAnswer class?

@fascynacja sorry that was a copy-paste error from an earlier piece of code I was playing with. It should have been just Answer. Edited to correct it.

Your solution works for me, just I wonder if there is anyway to declare this behaviour using @Mock annotation ( default config for all Mocks is impossible because I do not want to affect other tests cases)

Unfortunately the @Mock annotation only accepts a parameter taken from the Answers enum which is not flexible enough.

Final solution based on @k314159 answer is:

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoReturnListTest {

    private static final Answer<Object> ANSWER_WITH_NULL = (invocation) -> null;

    private final Properties myProperties = mock(Properties.class, ANSWER_WITH_NULL);

    @Test
    public void propertiesTest() {
        Set<String> propertyNames = myProperties.stringPropertyNames();
        System.out.println(propertyNames);
    }
}


To instruct Mockito to return null for all methods of a mock object by default, you can use the Mockito.RETURNS_DEFAULTS answer. This answer will return default values for all methods, which is null for non-primitive return types.
 @Mock(answer = Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
 Properties myProperties;

You can read more in the doc answers

I have tried this example and it`s working for me
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ExampleClassTest {

    @Mock(answer = Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
    ExampleClass exampleClass;

    @Test
    public void testGetFirstElement() {
        List<String> firstElement = exampleClass.getFirstElement();
        assertEquals(null, firstElement);
    }

}


this solution did not work for me. I am still getting an empty list.

I have updated my answer. I Forgot about Enum Answers. Please check

your solution after editing post gives me nullpointer: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Properties.stringPropertyNames()" because "this.myProperties" is null. Please3 mind the fact that I am stubbing a method which returns collection (Set or List)

Last update. what if you use @Mock(answer = Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS) and @ExtendWith annotation?

did it really work for you? What versions of libararies are you using?

Yep, it`s working for me. I am using mockito-junit-jupiter
5.7.0

maybe you can do the same example using the same code as mine? meaning using "java.util.Properties" and calling stringPropertyNames ?

You've got assertEquals(null, firstElement) and, to me, firstElement doesn't sound like a collection. The whole point of the question is collections need to be null, not empty. It seems you've got an element which is null, but that's not relevant to the question.
